# What is the asymptotic distribution of the integrated MSE of the histogram for a discrete random variable?

Tags: nonparametric, density-function

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be i.i.d. discrete random variables. Let $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{1}(X_i=x)$. I am interested in the asymptotic distribution of

$$\sum_x (f_n(x)-f(x))^2$$

I've tried expanding the square and rewriting the sum in many different ways. I got somewhere, but I feel like this is a known result published in a paper somewhere. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Preliminary working:** To facilitate our analysis, let $\mathscr{X}$ denote the support of the underlying discrete distribution.  Since the observable values are IID discrete values you clearly have:

$$f_n(x) \sim \frac{1}{n} \cdot \text{Bin}(n, f(x)) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{ for }x \in \mathscr{X}.$$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$ you therefore have the asymptotic distribution:

$$f_n(x) - f(x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{f(x)(1-f(x))}{n}} \cdot \text{N}(0, 1)\quad \quad \quad \text{for }x \in \mathscr{X}.$$

Hence, we have:

$$(f_n(x) - f(x))^2 \sim \frac{f(x)(1-f(x))}{n} \cdot \text{Chi-Sq}(1) \quad \quad \text{for }x \in \mathscr{X}.$$

These quantities are negatively correlated over $x \in \mathscr{X}$, owing to the fact that occurrence of one discrete outcome reduces the number of remaining values for the other outcomes.  However, they are asymptotically uncorrelated and so we can aggregate them as independent quantities in the asymptotic distribution.  (Showing this part formally would require more work - to do this you would show that the vector of above normal quantities has an asymptotic *multivariate* normal distribution, and derive the distribution of the sum of squares in that multivariate setting.)

---

**Asymptotic distribution of MSE:** If we ignore the negative correlation between values (since this tends to zero asymptotically for appropriately scaled quantities), then as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have the asymptotic distribution:

$$\text{MSE} \equiv \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} (f_n(x) - f(x))^2 \sim \frac{1}{n} \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} w(x) \cdot \text{Chi-Sq}(1),$$

where the weights $w(x) \equiv f(x)(1-f(x))$ depend on the underlying probabilities of the discrete outcomes.  Thus, asymptotically, the MSE is a weighted sum of chi-squared random variables each with one degree-of-freedom; it has the first two moments:

$$\mathbb{E}(\text{MSE}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} w(x) \quad \quad \quad \mathbb{V}(\text{MSE}) = \frac{2}{n^2} \sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} w(x)^2.$$

The asymptotic distribution does not have a closed form, but it is often approximated by applying the [Satterthwaite approximation](http://aix1.uottawa.ca/~glamothe/mat3378/Satterthwaite.pdf), which is a method-of-moments approximation using a single chi-squared distribution.  In this case the Satterthwaite approximation to the asymptotic distribution is:

$$\text{MSE} \overset{\text{Approx}}{\sim} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{\sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} w(x)^2}{\sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} w(x)} \cdot \text{Chi-Sq} \Bigg( \frac{(\sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} w(x))^2}{\sum_{x \in \mathscr{X}} w(x)^2} \Bigg).$$

Comment: Thanks for the outline. My only concern is the gap in going from the asymptotic distribution of $(f_n(x)-f(x))^2$ to the asymptotic distribution of $\sum_{x\in \mathscr{X}} (f_n(x)-f(x))^2$. I previously tried your approach, but I could never fill in that gap. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: The way you would do it more formally is to approximate the vector of scaled binomials by a *multivariate* normal, and you would have negative correlation between the values.  Then when you take the limit the negative correlation would go to zero (so long as you are looking at an appropriately scaled quantity).  You could then show that the vector norm (i.e., sum of squares) has a distribution that is equal to the above in the limit.  In the above exposition I have done an informal outline where I treat them individually, rather than giving the multivariate distribution.

Comment: Thanks. That's actually exactly what I did this afternoon. I got some different weights though. I also checked my answer numerically on an example and it worked well. That approximation was also really helpful and very accurate for the example I tried. Later I''ll comment with the weights I got. On my phone at the moment so a bit hard to type up the math.

Comment: You should post your analysis as an answer to this question.